# Alias for a chain of commands

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I have a `tool` with commands: `step1`, `step2` and `step3`.

I can chain them by calling:

`$ tool step1 step2 step3`

I would like to have an alias named `all` to run all the steps by calling:

`$ tool all`

I have found a solution that works but it doesn't seem right for me because of calling `cli()` twice under the hood:

```
@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    print('cli() has been called')

...

@cli.command()
def all():
    cli(args=['step1', 'step2', 'step3'])
```

How else could this be done without the side effect of calling `cli()` twice?

Comment: RE: the bounty, can you mention what concerns have not been [addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47985653/7311767)?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Stephen! It works but it's more like a workaround than a complete solution. The most significant issue is that aliases are not real commands and therefore not listed in `--help` output for example.

I have some ideas and I'll try to provide a better solution as a separate answer.

Comment: @StephenRauch And thank you for improving the question message itself!

Comment: Great idea RE the help message.  I have updated my answer to provide help documentation for aliases.  If there is anything that should be covered, let me know.

Answer (score 9):

One way to provide some aliases is to intercept the command and directly manipulate the `args` list. That can be done with a custom class like:

#### Custom Class

This class overrides the `click.Group.__call__()` method to allow editing the `args` list before calling the command processor.  In addition it overrides `format_epilog` to add help documentation for the aliases.

```
class ExpandAliasesGroup(click.Group):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.aliases = kwargs.pop('aliases', {})
        super(ExpandAliasesGroup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and args[0] and args[0][0] in self.aliases:
            alias = self.aliases[args[0][0]]
            args[0].pop(0)
            for command in reversed(alias):
                args[0].insert(0, command)
        return super(ExpandAliasesGroup, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def alias_help(self):
        return '\n'.join(
            '{}:  {}'.format(alias, ' '.join(commands))
            for alias, commands in sorted(self.aliases.items())
        )

    def format_epilog(self, ctx, formatter):
        """Inject our aliases into the help string"""

        if self.aliases:
            formatter.write_paragraph()
            formatter.write_text('Aliases:')
            with formatter.indentation():
                formatter.write_text(self.alias_help)

        # call the original epilog
        super(ExpandAliasesGroup, self).format_epilog(ctx, formatter)
```

#### Using the Custom Class

By passing the `cls` parameter, and a dict of aliases to the `click.group()` decorator, the `ExpandAliasesGroup` class can do alias expansion.

```
aliases = dict(all='command1 command2 command3'.split())

@click.group(chain=True, cls=ExpandAliasesGroup, aliases=aliases)
def cli():
    ....
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

By overriding the `__call__` method we can intercept all command calls.  Then if the list of args starts with a known alias, we edit the args list by removing that aliased command and replacing it with the aliases.

By overriding the `format_epilog` method we can add help documentation for the aliases.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

aliases = dict(all='command1 command2 command3'.split())

@click.group(cls=ExpandAliasesGroup, chain=True, aliases=aliases)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def command1():
    click.echo('Command 1')

@cli.command()
def command2():
    click.echo('Command 2')

@cli.command()
def command3():
    click.echo('Command 3')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'command1',
        'command3',
        'command1 command2',
        'all',
        '--help',
    )

    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            cli(cmd.split())
        except:
            pass
```

#### Test Results:

```
-----------
> command1
Command 1
-----------
> command3
Command 3
-----------
> command1 command2
Command 1
Command 2
-----------
> all
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND1 [ARGS]... [COMMAND2 [ARGS]...]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  command1  Command #1 comes first
  command2  Command #2 is after command #1
  command3  Command #3 saves the best for last

Aliases:
  all:  command1 command2 command3
```